# Why does an Exception thrown in a thread screw up my UI?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-11-alexandria

I use a `TThread` to send emails using Indy. It works great, and by using a separate thread, I avoid my apps UI freezing while `TIdSMTP` sends.

The problem is, if an exception occurs during sending, a lot of weird things start to happen in my app's UI.

For instance, I have a `TPanel` on the bottom used to show the current status. I feed this panel in every sending step, using events like `TIdSMTP.OnConnected` and `TIdSMTP.OnDisconnected`, for instance.

If an exception occur during sending, like for instance, 'Socket error', new updates to `Panel.Caption` 'mix' with prior panel captions, like this:

[image]

Also, my app's whole UI gets really screwed up, and the only way to fix it is to close the app and reopen it.

Looks like I'm doing something wrong in my thread exception handling, but I use threads a lot for other procedures and this issue happens only when I use `TIdSMTP`.

Is there something I need to do on `TIdSMTP` to avoid this weird behaviour?

Comment: Are you directly accessing visual components from your secondary threads or you do this through the using of Synchronize method?

Comment: @SilverWarior is rigth. Problem like this happens when you access to GUI in not safe way. If it's only when exception occurs - just look at your try..except block and send your exception to GUI in Synchronize block.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, i'm acessing visual components inside the thread. How would be the correct way to do this, please ?

Comment: @SilverWarior The problem was fixed after i started to Synchronize, thanks a lot ! Please post as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never be accessing UI components directly from any of your secondary threads. Doing so usually leads to race condition between your application code and Windows GUI system.

In best cases this would lead to visual glitches like the one you encountered. But in worst cases it could lead to instability or even crash of the whole windows UI.

So the correct way for accessing any UI elements is from your application main thread. In order to do so easily Delphi provides two methods:

1. [Synchronize](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) which forces for your code to be executed in main thread. It also suspends execution of the current thread while the method executes in the main thread.
2. [Queue](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) Unlike Synchronize, execution of the current thread is allowed to continue. The main thread will eventually process all queued methods.